# I know treeset prints elements in lexicographical order which is not happening here

Tags: java, collections, treeset

Can someone pls explain me the output of the 'obj' treeset here? I know treeset prints elements in lexicographical order which is not happening here.

enum Name {
Alice, Smith, Bob, Jones
}

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Name> obj = new TreeSet<>();
        obj.add(Name.Alice);
        obj.add(Name.Smith);
        obj.add(Name.Bob);

        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add("Alice");
        set.add("Smith");
        set.add("Bob");

        System.out.println("Enum set:");
        for (Name d : obj) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }

        System.out.println("\nNormal tree set:");
        for (String d : set) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }
}

**Output**

Enum set:
Alice
Smith
Bob

Normal tree set:
Alice
Bob
Smith
```

Comment: *Enums* are not *Strings*. The `compareTo()` Method of *enum*s uses the Constants index, not their names.

Comment: “…treeset prints elements in lexicographical order…” No, it doesn’t.  If constructed without a custom Comparator, a TreeSet assumes each element implements Comparable and uses that as the order.  For Strings, that is lexicographical order.  For enum values, that order is the order in which they’re defined in the enum type.

Comment: If you want the same behavior pass a comparator when declaring: `Set<Name> obj = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Enum::name));`

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You might have declared your `Enum` as shown below:

```
public enum Name {
    Alice,
    Smith,
    Bob
}
```

If you see the implementation of `compareTo()` method of the `Enum` class then its using `ordinal` of the enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

You need to declare your `Enum` constants as shown below to get desired results:

```
public enum Name {
    Alice,
    Bob,
    Smith
}
```

If you do not wish to modify the sequence of the `Enum` constants then you need to provide the `Comparator` while creating `TreeSet` instance as shown in below example:

```
Set<Name> obj = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Enum::name));
```

Comment: If I don't want to change the enum but still want the output in sorted order, how to do that? I tried to do this, but not working. Am I missing something here?
Set<Name> obj = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Name.values()));

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check!